# How to influence search path of System.loadLibrary() through Java code?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In a Java project, I am using a third-party library that loads some native library via

```
System.loadLibrary("libName");
```

I'd like to be able to influence the search path of this method from within my application, so that the user doesn't need to specify a correct java.library.path value on the command line (this value depends on the current OS and architecture). E.g on Windows I want to set it to "lib/native/windows", on Linux 32bit to "lib/native/linux32" etc.

I tried

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", ...)
```

but this is ignored, apparently because the JVM reads this property only once before my code is run.

I also tried to load the native libray before using the Java library that depends on it with

```
System.load("fullPath/lib")
```

This call succeeds, but there will still be an UnsatisfiedLinkError when the native library is loaded again with System.loadLibrary().

The only way I found is the following:

- Add interfaces that abstract the whole API of the external library.
- Use only these interfaces in the rest of the code.
- Add classes that implement the interfaces and delegate to the library.
- Write an own ClassLoader, that

  - overwrites findLibary() so that the native library is found in the correct path
  - overwrites loadClass() and loads all classes of the external library and the wrapper layer by itself instead of trying to delegate to its parent like the default ClassLoader would do
- Ensure that the interfaces are loaded with the normal ClassLoader and the wrapping classes and the external library are loaded with my own ClassLoader.

This works, but I find it very complicated and it is much effort because I need to add all those interfaces. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did or did it not work with `System.load("fullPath/lib/native/windows/libName.dll")`? And why are you reloading it with `System.loadLibrary(..)`?

Comment: @dacwe Yes, it did work. But the third-party library tries to load it again with System.loadLibrary(..), and this fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no approved way to change the library path for a running JVM.
2. You cannot load a native library more than once ... and you cannot unload a native library so that you can load it again: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4171986

Based on your comments above (particularly, the behavior of the 3rd-party library), I'd say that your best option is to get the library path right when you launch the JVM.

<sup>Note that there is a hacky way to change the library path (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258955/139985) but it involves nasty reflection, and it reportedly doesn't work for all Java releases.  Certainly, it relies on undocumented private implementation details of `ClassLoader` that *could* change from one release to the next.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

I needed to change the dll path for my unit tests. I tried the following hack and it worked:

```
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/path/to/libs" ); 
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

For explanation, see the [original link](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/).

Comment: Probably the most pragmatic way for unit tests, but I would not like to use this in production code.

Comment: Phillipp, of course it works inside of IDEs, too. For that 'runtime configurations' got invented. Just create a configuration, and set the environment variables correctly, put it under version control, so the others in the project gets it, too.

Comment: This approach will now cause a NullPointerException in Classloader.loadLibrary when running on openjdk.

Answer (score 2):

Just recently ran into this issue and using OpenJDK where a `NullPointerException` is thrown (as @0-0 mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013547/how-to-influence-search-path-of-system-loadlibrary-through-java-code/24258955#comment106689656_24258955) to Samil's answer). The following works in OpenJDK and *should* work with Oracle JDK as well.

## (Option 1) Replace the java.library.path

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", newPath);
Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new String[]{newPath});
```

## (Option 2) Add to existing java.library.path

```
String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
String newPath;

if (libPath == null || libPath.isEmpty()) {
    newPath = path;
} else {
    newPath = path + File.pathSeparator + libPath;
}

System.setProperty("java.library.path", newPath);

Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
field.setAccessible(true);
    
// Create override for sys_paths
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 
List<String> newSysPaths = new ArrayList<>();
newSysPaths.add(path);  
newSysPaths.addAll(Arrays.asList((String[])field.get(classLoader)));
           
field.set(classLoader, newSysPaths.toArray(new String[newSysPaths.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to following to load a native Growl library for a Java application on my Mac where the lib is in the root of the classpath of my application:

```
System.load(GrowlUtils.class.getResource("/libgrowl.jnilib").getFile().toString());
```

Comment: I am able to load the library in my own code, that's no problem. The problem is that third-party code loads the library with `System.loadLibrary("libName");`, so I need a way to influence the behavior of this method, not another way to load a library.

Comment: You could create a version of the class that uses a different call and place that version higher up in the classpath so it gets picked up first

Comment: Interesting idea, but quite ugly of course as you need to create that class (especially if its in a binary-only library) and you need to update it when the library gets updated.

Comment: I admit it is a dirty hack and might cause some additional work when upgrading, but we've had success with this approach in fixing/changing stuff in Liferay that we couldn't touch otherwise. However we did always have to original source available and didn't need to start from a decompiled class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simpler way?

Yes, provide batch/script files to start the application. Then you can set the correct path in the batch/shell file or even read the value from an environment variable. Much easier then trying to do it from inside the application.

Comment: Yes, that's we currently do. But that doesn't work for users starting it from within an IDE, or using it as an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score -1):

While technically correct these answers are missleading.  Setting the environment variables PATH on Windows, or LD_LIBRARY_PATH on unix will change where the jvm looks for libraries:
[What is LD_LIBRARY_PATH and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148036/what-is-ld-library-path-and-how-to-use-it)

on linux:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/.../
then:
java ....

Comment: I think that you have missed the point of the question.  It is about changing the library path of a JVM **that has already been launched**.  Changing environment variables won't help with that.  It is too late.