# Clojure, Lein, JavaFx, native deps

Tags: clojure, javafx-2, leiningen

### Context

I want to use JavaFx with clojure.

I am aware of http://nailthatbug.net/2011/06/clojure-javafx-2-0-simple-app/

### Question:

Is there a way to make JavaFX work with Clojure using native-deps in lein instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JavaFx has native dependencies your option are limited to, ]

- shipping these dependencies with your project (including them),
- creating a package that you can depend on which has them (providing them),
- or having your package require the user to install them in some other way.

Because the tutorial you link to covers the case where the user of your package/program installs JavaFx on their own, by using `robert.hook` and depending on the end-user's package manager to provide the actual native dependencies. I'll cover how to have your package/program include the dependencies.

[native-deps](https://github.com/swannodette/native-deps) can be used to ship native dependencies with your package. You just need to add all the .so, .dll, .etc files in the appropriate directories. I think the projects github page does a better job than I of explaining the structure.

Comment: Sorry, my question is unclear. My focus is _using_ JavaFX, not (yet) shipping FX. If I'm not misreading your link, that is about packaging native dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

I've created a simple [Clojure and JavaFX example on Github](https://github.com/raju-bitter/clojure-javafx-example). Testing on Ubuntu I had to install the JavaFX runtime into my local Maven repository, using the *deploy:deploy-file* target (install:install-file did not work for me).

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=local.oracle -DartifactId=javafxrt -Dversion=2.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar -Durl=file:/home/raju/.m2/repository
```

Make sure you have the following arguments set correctly:

- -Dfile={full path to jfxrt.jar in jre/lib folder}
- -Durl=file:{full path to Maven repository, e.g. $HOME/m2.repository}

In the project.clj, I added the dependency based on the -DgroupId and -DartifactId values when installing the JAR into the repository. If you use change these values, make sure to change the dependency accordingly:

```
[local.oracle/javafxrt "2.2.0"]
```

Java was able to load the binary libraries without any problems. If Java reports problems loading a binary library, e.g.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk/rt/lib/amd64/libglass.so

check out these two question on SO:

[What is LD_LIBRARY_PATH and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148036/what-is-ld-library-path-and-how-to-use-it)
[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError no *****.dll in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path)

Answer (score 1):

The link in the question is broken so I can't see your example, but with Java 8, JavaFX is now part of the standard JDK/JRE. I therefore expect the native dependency issue to be irrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for others, but this appears (so far) to have worked for me:

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javafx -DartifactId=javafx -Dversion=2.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar

I have no idea why this works, but I believe jfxrt.jar has the files I need. Then, after this, I kindle it in project.clj as

```
[javafx "2.1.0"]
```

in the :dependencies (not :native-deps) section.

[Having written this, I really have no idea why this even appears to work.]

Comment: java is likely able to load the native lib dependencies directly from your computer by looking in (assuming linux) LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The jar file contains essentially a list of the dependencies it needs loaded and leaves it up to java to find them on the local filesystem.