# Include platform-specific java dependencies (without setting my hair on fire)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I would like to make use of the [HDF5 java library](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/) from Clojure. Unfortunately, the usual way of including java dependencies (i.e. via Leiningen's support for Maven repositories) isn't available. This is likely because the HDF5-Java library is a JNI-wrapped set of compiled C++ and Fortran code.

I looked at Maven-izing a recent version of HDF5-Java, but didn't understand how platform-specific versions were handled there / decided that was far too much of a pain. Assuming I'm stuck using platform-specific jars released by the HDF group, is there a relatively good way to handle these, while continuing to mostly live within the comfortable world of Leiningen?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this myself, but it looks like you should be able to native dependencies in Leiningen by packaging up the HDF5 library into a JAR file following the directory structure described [here](https://github.com/swannodette/native-deps), installing it in Maven, and adding a regular dependency on that library in `project.clj`. Leiningen should handle the dirty work of detecting your OS and architecture and including the correct parts on your project classpath.

For more reading, check out:

http://nakkaya.com/2010/04/05/managing-native-dependencies-with-leiningen/

http://bially.posterous.com/using-jogl-in-your-clojure-project

[Clojure, Lein, JavaFx, native deps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111467/clojure-lein-javafx-native-deps)

Comment: Slowly working through this to see if I can make this approach work. One tricky bit was that if I just throw the whole platform-specific tree into native branches, I end up with a 40MB jar--too big for clojars. So, I'm trying to be a little smarter about separating the platform-specific stuff from the cross-platform stuff. Hopefully my thrashing around on clojars doesn't draw sharks.