# Include .so library into another in Qt

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I try to include one dynamic library(.so) into another. Than I include first library into app. `TDS-Converter/Converter` it's directory with source code. With this config I get error when try to call any function of second library via `undefined reference to`.

```
QT -= gui
TEMPLATE = lib

unix {
    DEPENDPATH += . ../../TDS-Converter/Converter
    INCLUDEPATH +=  ../../TDS-Converter/Converter
    LIBS += ../../TDS-Converter/Converter/Converter -lConverter
}
win32 {
}

SOURCES += main.cpp\
   ...

HEADERS += \ 
    ...
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `LIBS` seems wrong, it should probably be

```
LIBS += -L../../TDS-Converter/Converter/Converter -lConverter
```

...and double-check the file really is this, and fix if not:

`../../TDS-Converter/Converter/Converter/libConverter.so`

---

If you're talking about runtime, then read on:

The other library is not "inluded" in your library, it is *used* by your library. So it needs to be available at runtime. A quick fix, set [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148036/what-is-ld-library-path-and-how-to-use-it) to the `../../TDS-Converter/Converter/Converter` directory, when running an application which uses your library.

Alternatives to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable are

- use [*rpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl), which puts the preferred library search path into the executable. Downside is, this needs to be decided at compile time.
- Copy libConverter.so to some current system include directory, and run `ldconfig` to refresh library cache. Downside is, you need root and clutter system library directories.
- Add the directory where libConvereter.so is to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or preferably to a new file under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`), and run `ldconfig` to refresh library cache. Downside is, you need root, and clutter system configuration.