# Difference between using java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Is there a difference between setting the JVM argument

```
-Djava.library.path=/path
```

at JVM start and setting the Linux environment variable

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path
```

before the JVM is started?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of the two approaches?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The first form**

```
-Djava.library.path=/path
```

will be handled in java bytecode level, `System.loadLibrary` will call `Runtime.loadLibary`, then will call `java/lang/ClassLoader.loadLibrary`. In the function call `ClassLoader.loadLibrary`, the system property `java.library.path` will be checked to get the full path of the library and pass this full path to native code to call system api `dlopen/dlsym`, eventually make the library loaded. You can browse the source from [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java) repository. The following code snippet is the segment I copy from the link.

The advantage of this form is that you will get error or warning or exception in Java code, if there are some problems with your library path.

```
// Invoked in the java.lang.Runtime class to implement load and loadLibrary.
static void loadLibrary(Class fromClass, String name,
                        boolean isAbsolute) {
    ClassLoader loader =
        (fromClass == null) ? null : fromClass.getClassLoader();
    if (sys_paths == null) {
        usr_paths = initializePath("java.library.path");
        sys_paths = initializePath("sun.boot.library.path");
    }
    if (isAbsolute) {
        if (loadLibrary0(fromClass, new File(name))) {
            return;
        }
        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Can't load library: " + name);
    }
// ....
```

**The second form**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path
```

will be handled in native, according to the document of `dlopen/dlsym`

```
 dlopen()
   The function dlopen() loads the dynamic library file named by the null-terminated string filename and returns an opaque  "handle"  for  the
   dynamic  library.   If  filename is NULL, then the returned handle is for the main program.  If filename contains a slash ("/"), then it is
   interpreted as a (relative or absolute) pathname.  Otherwise, the dynamic linker searches for the library as follows (see ld.so(8) for fur‐
   ther details):

   o   (ELF  only)  If  the  executable  file for the calling program contains a DT_RPATH tag, and does not contain a DT_RUNPATH tag, then the
       directories listed in the DT_RPATH tag are searched.

   o   If, at the time that the program was started, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-separated list of
       directories, then these are searched.  (As a security measure this variable is ignored for set-user-ID and set-group-ID programs.)
```

In this manner, if there are some problems with your library path and the system can't load your library, the system won't give too much clue what happen and will fail silently (I guess). It depends whether or not to implement `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, Android didn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to determine the library location, you can see Android's implementation from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Runtime.java).

Comment: Notably (but as you might expect from this difference), loading native libraries that reference others (ala -lboost or whatever) _will not_ find the referenced libs in the `java.library.path`, but _will_ find them in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: On Linux systems (tried it on Centos), value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets prepending in java.library.path system property. On my MacOS that does not happen

Answer (score 5):

Java can explicitely load libaries listed with  `-Djava.library.path=...` 
as described by alijandro.

For example, if mq series is used in bindings mode, the path for the neccessary libraries can be specified with     `-Djava.library.path=/opt/mq/java/lib` and mqseries loads the libraries.

If a library is not explcitely loaded from java, i.e. a dependent library has to be used, then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has to be used to have that library available in the jvm.