# How to make OpenCV-3.1.0 Java "x64" native library folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using **Ubuntu-14.04** and I have installed **OpenCV-3.1.0** according to the commands given in [this link](https://udallascs.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/adding-opencv-and-configuring-to-work-with-eclipse-and-java/). I was able to build the **jar properly**. I'm using it in a NetBeans project.

I want to add the location of java **x64 folder** in to the **VM options of the IDE**. But It seems like I haven't built that folder to add the path and I'm getting the exception as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path"

I had already installed "Apache Ant" and these required packages before installing OpenCV.

```
    GCC 4.4.x or later
    CMake 2.6 or higher
    Git
    GTK+2.x or higher, including headers (libgtk2.0-dev)
    pkg-config
    Python 2.6 or later and Numpy 1.5 or later with developer packages (python-dev, python-numpy)
    ffmpeg or libav development packages: libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libswscale-dev
    libtbb2 libtbb-dev
    libdc1394 2.x
    libjpeg-dev, libpng-dev, libtiff-dev, libjasper-dev, libdc1394-22-dev
```

But I couldn't build that native library folder. Please mention how should I proceed. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945268/difference-between-using-java-library-path-and-ld-library-path

Comment: Have you built the native shared library (`libopencv_<something>.so.3.1`)?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I found it as "libopencv_java310.so" in the default installed location. I thought in ubuntu it comes as "x64 " folder and it was incorrect. After giving this "libopencv_java310.so"' path in VM options,program is working properly.