# Get tomcat to spill system properties

Tags: java, tomcat, system-properties

I googled everything I could think of and couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know a way to get tomcat to dump the output of System.getProperties() of the current runtime environment? It would certainly be useful to have sometimes.

Comment: Either deploy a web application that does exactly that or try to see if that data is available using jmx.

Comment: To the downvoter, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Maybe because your question doesn't show efforts to solve by yourself. But it wasn't me.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks @EugèneAdell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually copy-paste the values if you use the java mission control tool:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jmc
```

Start a JMX console against your Tomcat's JVM process, then look under the `System` tab. You can see all values and copy the values under `System properties`.

[image]

You may need to check [the documentation on enabling remote JMX](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote) if you're going to do this from a remote machine.

Answer (score 4):

Besides Java Mission Control, you can do it using jcmd. First list Java processes with:

```
$ JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd
```

Then enter the PID of the Tomcat process:

```
$ JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd <pid> VM.system_properties
```

Answer (score 1):

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437034/7748072), create a JSP with this content :

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Properties" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Set" %>

<%
Properties p = System.getProperties();

Set<String> keys = p.stringPropertyNames();
for (String key : keys)
  out.println(key + " : " + p.getProperty(key));

%>
```

Remember you shouldn't disclose this to anyone but the admin (even the dev team shouldn't know the database password for example, if stored in a property).

Comment: Of course I could write code to do it. I was wondering if there was a way to view with tomcat out of the box.

Comment: @Thom  If you read your own question carefully, my answer is acceptable. Another solution was given already by f1sh, based on JMX, but it's not exactly a dump. We cannot always assume of the skills behind the question. The answer can look obious, or not.