# What is the proper way to load native libraries with gradle?

Tags: java

I have multiple native libraries for java that I need to load from java code. Project is gradle based and I couldn't find any way to make libraries load the same way as they are in Android (jniLibs directory).

Comment: You mean they are not found at runtime?

Comment: Yes they are not found during runtime, and I can't find a way to modify runtime library path variable.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148036/what-is-ld-library-path-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Problem is that I want to store native libs inside project. That project is developed by multiple people and some of them are not even developers, for that the easiest would be to use gradle