# Loading dll using loadLibrary

Tags: java, java-native-interface, 64-bit, environment-variables

I am currently maintaining a Java communication library which wraps the functionality offered by some dll via JNI. At some point, in Java, I need to load the JNI wrapper to forward my requests and finally call the native library. Currently, this is accomplished by calling

```
System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary");
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java), this should always find `MyLibrary` if it is placed somewhere within `java.library.path`. Currently, my `java.library.path` seems to include some Java specific folders as well as all directories specified in the %PATH% environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16; 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;   
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32;
C:\MyFolder\Common32;
C:\MyFolder\Common64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;.
```

My problem now is that even though `MyLibrary` is placed in `C:\MyFolder\Common64;` the above `loadLibrary` call yields an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` and I cannot seem to understand why. It is however found when I put it into the `System32` folder, or if I instead call `load` while specifying the path absolutely:

```
System.load("C:\\MyFolder\\Common64\\MyLibrary.dll");
```

I tried to mess around with the `java.library.path` during runtime using the `sys_path` trick suggested in the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29286387/586380) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258955/586380). The following works flawlessly:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\MyFolder\\Common64\\" );

Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null ); 

System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary");
```

So, if I replace the entire `java.library.path` property with a custom path the dll is successfully loaded. However, this is not the desired behavior, as I want to find the dll dynamically by adding the correct directory to %PATH%. Furthermore, adding my custom path to `java.library.path` like so

```
String curJavaLibraryPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
System.setProperty("java.library.path", curJavaLibraryPath + ";C:\\MyFolder\\Common64\\" );
```

also does not work.

Currently I am trying to make this work on a Win7 64-bit machine. My dll is also compiled as x64, if that's relevant.

---

The general procedure works flawlessly when I compile my Java library in x86 mode and copy the according JNI dll to `C:\MyFolder\Common32\` and add that directory to %PATH%.

Comment: Is the jdk or jre running the application in 64bit? Have you tried to put the dll in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`directory?

Comment: Loading the dll already works when I put it in the `System32` folder (on a x64 system this is the place where you put x64 libs). However, I want the dll to be found dynamically by letting the user put it wherever he/she wants and then adding an entry with the according folder to `PATH`

Comment: So, have you gone to this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/ and/or that https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp

Comment: Yes, I know about the `-D` flag and also about setting the `java.library.path` via the IDE. But this does not help me as I only want to rely on the %PATH% variable. I just cannot figure out, why it would not load the dll even though it is already in the correct path.

Comment: What you exactly want to do? Put the file in the %PATH% or load it from a custom directory? If you want to put it on the "default" Windows %PATH%, then you have to put the dll to one of the folders listed by calling `echo %PATH%` at the command prompt. If you want to load it from a custom directory, you have to load it with System.load("Path to dll") and **not** with System.loadLibrary(). Or you have to modify your %PATH% Variable, but this sometimes needs a reboot of your machine.

Comment: You get *what* `UnsatisfiedLinkError`? Do you really get it on `loadLibrary(),` or when calling a JNI method?

Comment: I will elaborate on my question

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me. If not with the directory itself then maybe with the path separator. ":" does look a lot like ";"

Comment: Oh, and recently there was some other person where the PATH was too long. Does it work if you put you directory at the start?

Comment: Calling `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\MyFolder\\Common64\\;" + curJavaLibraryPath );` actually works for me. Consequently, I tried to move my custom directory to the beginning of %PATH%, which, to my surprise, did not have any effect, however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the [loadLibrary() Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) has managed to fool me a bit. In case of an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` it states

> UnsatisfiedLinkError - if the library does not exist.

Therefore, I obviously assumed that `loadLibrary()` at no point was capable of seeing my specified library. That is, however, not the case as this exception can also mean that it found the according library in a wrong (incompatible with the VM) bitness.

As far as I understand it, the only check you can do to find out which `UnsatisfiedLinkError` you have exactly, is to break down the error message contained by the exception. What I ended up doing is along the lines of:

```
try
{
    System.setProperty(JAVA_LIBPATH_PROPNAME, libpath);  
    ForceReloadLibraryPath();
    System.loadLibrary("AdsToJava");        
}
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex)
{
    // We simply did not find the dll
    if (ex.getMessage().equals("no MyLibrary in java.library.path")) {

        // Just alert that nothing was found

    } else if ( (ex.getMessage().endsWith("Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform")) || 
                (ex.getMessage().endsWith("Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform")) ) {

        // Extract the path at which the dll whith the wrong bitness was found 
        // and remove it from the search path and try again
    }
}
```

You could obviously also pre-check the search path prior to calling `loadLibrary` but as this method also works in cases where users copy the dlls allover the search path I thought this to be the most powerful option.

Comment: What is ForceReloadLibraryPath?

Comment: Sorry mate. Neither do I remember after all these year, nor do I still have access to the project. Did you try without that call already?

Comment: ForceReloadLibraryPath is probably manipulating some cached private information in ClassLoader.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409223/adding-new-paths-for-native-libraries-at-runtime-in-java for possible approaches (which depend on the target JVM version).