# Why can't I get java bindings (GDAL) to work

Tags: java

I downloaded Gdal release-1928-x64-gdal-3-2-1-mapserver-7-6-2-libs.zip and decompressed it to   C:\Program Files\Gdal_321.
I tried to get help from gdal-dev for three weeks now, but without any luck.

I allways get the message:
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-1.b09.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\jre\bin\gdalalljni.dll:  The specified procedure cannot be found
when I try to execute System.loadLibrary("gdalalljni")

Setup:
Windows 10 64-bit with x64 based processor
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
The Java I’m using is: java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-1.b09.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64
Installed release-1928-x64-gdal-3-2-1-mapserver-7-6-2-libs.zip in C:\Program Files\Gdal_321

Then I copied the gdalalljni.dll to C:\Program Files\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-1.b09.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\jre\bin
Added the following to the system path:
C:\Program Files\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-1.b09.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre\bin
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\java
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\apps
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\python\osgeo
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj7\apps
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\ms\apps
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\csharp
C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\curl

Added the following system variables:
GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal-data
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins-external;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins-optional
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201-1.b09.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\jre
PROJ_LIB=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj7\share

Then I added C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\java\gdal.jar to my class-path

When I’m executing the program I get:
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre\bin\gdalalljni.dll: The specified procedure cannot be found

Then I’ve installed dependency Walker 22_x64.
I don’t know how to use it, but when I load gdalalljni.dll I get the following errorcodes:
[See dependecy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wQsA.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Method [loadLibrary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)), in class `java.lang.System` searches the list of directories that is the value of [System] property `java.library.path` which is, by default, set to the value of the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.

Either change the value of PATH or explicitly set `java.library.path` when you launch your java program (using the [-D option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE)) or use method [load](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)) (instead of `loadLibrary`) and supply the full path to file `gdalalljni.dll`.

Refer to [How to influence search path of System.loadLibrary() through Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013547/how-to-influence-search-path-of-system-loadlibrary-through-java-code)

Comment: Thanks, I itried to set the environment path to where I have gdalalljni.dll but there was no difference.

Comment: @Paul print out the value of `java.library.path` (System property) to see if the path to the directory containing file `gdalalljni.dll` appears. Also, are you certain that the name of the library is `gdalalljni`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, there are two pathes to different java lib when I print the java.libray path: 
 C:/Users/rty/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin/server;  
C:/Users/rty/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin;  
C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre\bin\   The last one I've set and there is where gdalalljni.dll is placed. Yes gdalalljni.dll is the name.

Comment: how do you print out the value of 'java.library.path'?

Comment: @user1034912 `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Answer (score -1):

I mixed upp the gdalalljni.dll and gdal305.dll I copied to my Java\bin with a gdalalljni.dll resp gdal305.dll from a nother gdal release.